# Get the rows of dataframe based on the consecutive values of one column

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, iteration, rows

Are there way to get consecutive rows according to value of specific column?
For example:

|  | column1 | column2 | View |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| row1 | 1 | 2 | c |
| row2 | 3 | 4 | a |
| row3 | 5 | 6 | p |
| row4 | 7 | 8 | p |
| row5 | 9 | 10 | n |

I need to get the rows that have the letter of word 'app' as View, so in this example I need to save **row2, row3 and row4** in a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the pythonic way, but doing the work:

```
keep = []
for i in range(len(df) - 2):
    if (df.View[i]=='a') & (df.View[i+1] =='p') & (df.View[i+2] =='p'):
        keep.append(df[i])
        keep.append(df[i+1])
        keep.append(df[i+2])
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This line `for i,_ in enumerate(range(len(df)))` is the weirdest way I've seen anyone do `for i in range(len(df))`. also, why do you need `if i+3==len(df): break`? just do `for i in range(len(df) - 2)`

Comment: and third, why do you keep the indices of the rows instead of just keeping the rows? instead of `keep.append(i)`, use `keep.append(df[i])` and then you don't need to use `df.iloc` at the end, you just have the rows in `keep`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a generalizable approach. I use `index_slice_by_substring()` to generate a tuple of integers representing the beginning and ending row. The function `rows_by_consecutive_letters()` takes your dataframe, the column name to check, and the string you want to look for, and for the return value it utilizes `.iloc` to grab a slice of the table by integer values.

The key to getting the slice indices is joining the "View" column values together into a single string using `''.join(df[column])` and checking substrings of the same length as the condition string from left to right until there's a match

```
def index_slice_by_substring(full_string, substring) -> tuple:
    len_substring = len(substring)
    len_full_string = len(full_string)
    for x0, x1 in enumerate(range(len_substring,len_full_string)):
        if full_string[x0:x1] == substring:
            return (x0,x1)

def rows_by_consecutive_letters(df, column, condition) -> pd.DataFrame:
    row_begin, row_end = index_slice_by_substring(''.join(df[column]), condition)
    return df.iloc[row_begin:row_end,:]

print(rows_by_consecutive_letters(your_df,"View","app"))
```

Returns:

```
   column1  column2 View
1        3        4    a
2        5        6    p
3        7        8    p
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.find` but this only finds the first occurrence of your search term.

```
search = 'app'
i = ''.join(df.View).find(search)
if i>-1:
    print(df.iloc[i: i+len(search)])
```

Output

```
      column1  column2 View                         
row2        3        4    a
row3        5        6    p
row4        7        8    p
```

---

To find none (without error checking), one and all occurrences you can use `re.finditer`. The result is a list of dataframe slices.

```
import re
search='p'   # searched for 'p' to find more than one
[df.iloc[x.start():x.end()] for x in re.finditer(search, ''.join(df.View))]
```

Output

```
[      column1  column2 View                        
 row3        5        6    p,
       column1  column2 View                         
 row4        7        8    p]
```

Comment: Nice, but doesn't work if there is more than one triplet in the df.

Comment: @NivDudovitch - added a solution for multiple occurrences.